# undefined method `TimeDifference' for #<ReportsController:0x007f21ac69dd20>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying [time_difference gem](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference) to subtract 2 datetime and sum the result which grouped by month, with this code

```html
downtime = @Ticket.sum(TimeDifference(:start_time, :restore_time)).in_hours.round.group_by { |t| t.due_at.beginning_of_month }
```

but it end up showing the No Method Error message for TimeDifference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the readme, you'll notice that the method is

```
TimeDifference.between(time1, time2)
```

You are missing `.between`.

Also, the values you're passing as arguments (`:start_time`, `:end_time`) are not time objects, they are symbols. You should read up on the difference between variables and symbols if this isn't clear.

Furthermore, `.in_hours.round` returns an integer. So your `group_by` will raise a NoMethodError. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `group_by` here, since you don't have an iterable.

Comment: after i add the "between" it come out with the error "undefined method `to_time' for :start_time:Symbol"

Comment: Yes, since like I mentioned in my answer `:start_time` is a symbol, not a variable/Time object.